# Error accessing a property from a sub class in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

While accessing a property from a sub class in JSF, it fails with the error below:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /grouptable/Create.xhtml @19,281 value="#{grouptableController.selected.grouptablePK.groupid}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1008)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:934)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1189)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:691)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1080)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:243)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1080)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1080)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1180)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Has anyone see this before? Please help. I am using glassfish v3.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> value="#{grouptableController.selected.grouptablePK.groupid}": 
> Target Unreachable, 'null'
> ```

This basically means that one of the nested properties is `null`. In this context, it can be can be either `selected` or `grouptablePK` which has returned null. Those shouldn't be null whenever JSF needs to set the `groupid` property.

You need to preinstantiate those nested objects/beans yourself. JSF/EL won't do that for you.

Thus, instead of

```
public class ParentBean {
    private ChildBean childBean;
}
```

you need to do

```
public class ParentBean {
    private ChildBean childBean = new ChildBean();
}
```

or

```
public class ParentBean {
    private ChildBean childBean;
    public ParentBean() {
        this.childBean = new ChildBean();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the `ChildBean` is also a managed bean, or can be one, then you can also make use of managed property injection in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>parentBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.ParentBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>childBean</property-name>
        <value>#{childBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>childBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.ChildBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: I have the same situation BalusC. `#{document.selectedDrawing.name} Target Unreachable, "null"`. `document` is the managed bean. `Drawing selectedDrawing` where `Drawing` is the entity class. What I dont understand is that, it display the name of the selected drawing correctly. But then when I click to the `commandButton` to link to somewhere else, it pop that error. I dont understand if it already display the correct value, then how `selectedDrawing` be `null`. I read your post, and try `selectedDrawing = new Drawing()`, it fix it, but created another drawing inside my database.

Comment: @Harry: Lazy loading issue in your persistence layer?

Comment: In my managed bean, I used lazy loading to load all the `Drawing` to a `list<Drawing>`. I dont think I use any in my session bean

Comment: I changed lazy loading to inject `@PostConstruct` to `public void init()`. And it still does not fix it. If u can help me a bit, I would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a hard time interpreting the error, what it means is that on your facelets page, it can't figure out what you mean by:

```
#{grouptableController.selected.grouptablePK.groupid}
```

Hope this helps.